# correct way to refer enum items of `boost::date_time`

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

```
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"

int main()
{
    boost::gregorian::greg_weekday dWeek(boost::date_time::Wednesday);

    //Code One
    // warning C4482: nonstandard extension used: enum 'boost::date_time::weekdays' used in qualified name
    if (dWeek.as_enum()==boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::weekday_enum::Wednesday)
    {
        std::cout << "Today is Wednesday" << std::endl;
    }

    //class BOOST_DATE_TIME_DECL greg_weekday : public greg_weekday_rep {
    //public:
    //    typedef boost::date_time::weekdays weekday_enum;

    //Code Two
    if (dWeek.as_enum()==boost::date_time::Wednesday)
    {
        std::cout << "Today is Wednesday" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Question**> I have seen tons of code that use **Code One** to do the comparison of `boost::date_time`. Based on C++ standard, the usage of the enum is incorrect. I have provided a solution as **Code Two**.

Can someone give me quick look and see whether it real is CORRECT way to do comparison?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: correction

use

```
boost::date_time::Wednesday
```

I didn't look at what type as_enum() returned. Fixed it, compiles & works (on MSVC2k10, Boost 1.48.0 self-built)

EDIT2: You'll find it buried away inside boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_facet.hpp.

```
namespace boost{
namespace gregorian{
  typedef boost::date_time::weekdays weekday_enum;
}
}
```

Anyway the relevant part for the rest of the info is that there's a boost::date_time::weekdays::Wednesday, but we take out weekdays.

Enums are basically like:

```
enum foo { bar = 1, barre = 2, barred = 3 };
// Is sort-of the same as
typedef static const int foo;
foo bar = 1;
foo barre = 2;
foo barred = 3;
```

foo is not a namespace, nor is it a struct, or anything like that, it is more of a typename.

I know it's not *exactly* the same, but it may as well be for the purposes of using them. Using the weekday_enum qualifier inside a type like that is basically giving the compiler a tiny bit of garbage to parse, it's like saying:

```
typedef int foo;
struct S {
  static foo var;
} p;

p.foo::var = 4; // Does this make sense? Nope...
```

Comment: No. boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::Wednesday causes error C2039: 'Wednesday' : is not a member of 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday'

Comment: @q0987 sorry, my fault, fixed it. I didn't check what type as_enum() returned.